# Python mutiprocessing restarts script with unknown arguments

Tags: python, multiprocessing, windows-10, pyinstaller

I used package my script with pyinstaller and run it with the same setup that I use now. However, now the multiprocessing routine does not work anymore.

Instead of running the multiprocessing part the script is repeatedly called with unknown arguments.

> Mint.exe: error: unrecognized arguments: --multiprocessing-fork parent_pid=1240 pipe_handle=4976

Apparently, adding `if __name__ == '__main__':` before the main routine should prevent that restarting error. That was always there, and still is, thought now the script gets restarted in Windows 10.

Python version is 3.8.5.

Any ideas? The `__name__ == '__main__'` thing does not solve the problem.

Comment: Please provide a [mcve].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this,

```
from multiprocessing import freeze_support
if __name__ == '__main__':
    freeze_support()
```

Comment: I am going to try this now. It seems it also has something to do with pyinstaller. When I start the script without it, it works.